# Find and replace italics in Word document with Python win32com

Tags: python, replace, ms-word, com, win32com

I'm facing a big issue with the Python package win32com: My problem is that I want to find some words in a Word document, and put them in italics.

Let's say I have the word "Hello" 10 times in my document. I want to reach all these 10 occurrences of the word "Hello", and write them in italics.

Any idea on how to do that? I've been looking for a solution for several months and I couldn't find one!

Many thanks!

Comment: Show your attempts or some code.

Comment: Actually I don't really have something to show you, the command I use to replace words is the following : `app.Selection.Find.Execute("Hello", False, False, False, False, False, True, wdFindContinue, False, "Good morning", wdReplaceAll)`

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to avoid using `wdReplaceAll` and instead simply do

```
import win32com.client
import os

word = win32com.client.Dispatch('Word.Application')
word.Documents.Open(os.path.abspath(r'.\your_document.docx'))
while word.Selection.Find.Execute('Hello'):
    word.Selection.Range.Font.Italic = True
```

Here, we continuously search for `'Hello'` and, for each search result, use the fact that the match becomes available as the selected range.

Note that this does not wrap around the search, so if that becomes necessary in your case (which it might if you can not ensure that the search is started at the beginning of the document), you may want to use [`wdFindContinue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224337(v=office.11).aspx) (and take care to avoid potential infinite loops).